# Retrieving values from another table which has its relationship to the first table defined by a third table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Right now I have

```
SELECT 
    table1.field1 AS whatever
    , table2.field2 AS stuff

FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.goId = table2.Id
```

I need to be able to select a `field3` which is located in a `table3`. Thing is, `table1` has no direct foreign key pointing to `table3`, but it DOES have foreign key that points to a table which has another foreign key pointing to `table3`. How do I make the join between these 3 tables?

Comment: What table is the foreign key in table 1 pointing to ?

Comment: it points to a fourth table which is the one that only has 2 columns, one points to table 1 and the other points to table 3.

Comment: Might be beneficial to set up a fiddle detailing the other tables structures

Comment: let us ignore all the other crap and I´ll edit only what is relevant to my problem, I will edit the code shortly,

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of database structure provided the following could be used

```
SELECT
    --Put column Declarations here--
    table1.columnName1
    ,table2.columnName2
    ,table3.columnName3
FROM
    table1 
    JOIN table2 ON table1.columnName1 = table2.columnName1
    JOIN table4 ON table1.columnName1 = table4.columnName1
    JOIN table3 ON table4.columnName4 = table3.columnName4
```

OR you could nest the third table

```
SELECT
    --Put column Declarations here--
    table1.columnName1
    ,table2.columnName2
    ,table3.columnName3
FROM
    table1 
    JOIN table2 ON table1.columnName1 = table2.columnName1
    JOIN table4 
        JOIN table3 ON table4.columnName4 = table3.columnName4
    ON table1.columnName1 = table4.columnName1
```

Answer (score 1):

Say that fourth table is table2.

```
SELECT 
    table3.column_You_want 
FROM 
    table3 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.column_linked_to_table3 = table3.column_name_linked_to_table2
    INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.column_linked_to_table1 = table1.column_linked_to_table2
```